# Health Data plugin for NativeScript in plan JS

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I am trying to add this plugin to my NativeScript project in plan JS. 
But I don't know how to convert this TypeScript into JS. Can anyone please help me.

Here is the link: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-health-data

```
import { AggregateBy, HealthData, HealthDataType } from "nativescript-health-data";

export class MyHealthyClass {
  private healthData: HealthData;

  constructor() {
    this.healthData = new HealthData();
  }
}
```

Comment: You remove typings from TS, what's left is mostly your JS code. In the above snippet I think you can completely remove `private healthData: HealthData;`, that should be it. You may also use any online compilers or TS CLI to convert your code into JS.

Comment: Smart! But it didn't work, it says lib dont find. Is there any other way you can help me? I so hope so!!

Comment: I guess your JS part is fixed now. If you have further errors please post extract error log, whether it's runtime or compile time.